# Ecto joins returning nil records

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I have two ecto queries, say query1 and query2, now I am performing full join between those two ecto queries, something like this

```
query1 |> join(:full, [a], b in subquery(query2), a.id == b.id)
```

Everything is working fine, but some of the records are returned as nil, something like this

```
[%user{}, %user{}, %user{}, nil, %user{}, %user{}, nil, %user{}, %user{}, nil]
```

I think the same issue has also been discussed in this [ecto thread.](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/1876)

Is there some workaround for this ecto join issue.

Answer (score 0):

That Ecto thread is a separate issue. :)

You are using a full join, which means the left and right side of a join will be returned even when there is no match. If you use an `:inner` join, it should work as expected:

```
query1 |> join(:inner, [a], b in subquery(query2), a.id == b.id)
```

If you need to keep a full join, maybe you want to return both `a` and `b` in your example?

```
query1
|> join(:inner, [a], b in subquery(query2), a.id == b.id)
|> select([a, b], {a, b})
```

This way it is guaranteed *one* of them is not nil.

Comment: Or `:left` join OR `... |> Enum.reject(& is_nil(&1))` with his query since he may need those which are not associated with subquery

Comment: @José inner join will just return me the matching records only, I want matching records as well as non matching records. So inner join will not satisfy my requirements.

Comment: If you have to use a full_join then you will receive nils. Maybe you want to return both `a` and `b` though? I have updated my answer.